# Wait for the HTTP request to be completed to continue the rest of the script in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, observable

I have a function `getData()` that calls an API, processes the data, transforms, and saves it to a  **BehaviorSubject**. Then returns the processed data as an observable using **of()**.

**getData()**

```
getData(fId: string | null = null) {

    // get the data to tempItems with an API Call
    this.getDataFromAPI().subscribe(data => {
        this.tempItems = [data]
    })

    let items = cloneDeep(this.tempItems);

    // Separate the items by folders and files
    const a: Item[] = items.filter(item => item.type === 'a');
    const b: Item[] = items.filter(item => item.type !== 'b');

    const path: Item[] = [];
    //do some work

    // Create  data

    let data = {
        folders: a,
        files: b,
        path
    }

    // Add this data to the BehaviorSubject
    this._items.next(data);

    return of(data);
}
```

**getDataFromAPI()**

```
    getDataFromAPI() {
    return this._httpClient.get(URL);
}
```

In the `getData()` function the variable `this.tempItems` is undefined in run time. Because of the HTTP call, the rest of the script is not waiting for the HTTP request to be finished.

How can I properly use Async Await here? and still, manage to return the `of(data)`

The function which call the getData() function expects an observable in return

Comment: the function which call the `getData()` function expects an observable in return

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Comment: Not really. I am using this service with resolver. And accessing the data from the BehaviourSubject in `ngOnInit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use operators like this:

```js
getData(fId: string | null = null) {

    return this.getDataFromAPI().pipe(
        tap(data => {
            this.tempItems = [data]
        }),
        map(data => {
             let items = cloneDeep([data]);

             // Separate the items by folders and files
             const a: Item[] = items.filter(item => item.type === 'a');
             const b: Item[] = items.filter(item => item.type !== 'b');

             const path: Item[] = [];
             //do some work

            // Create  data

            return {
                folders: a,
                files: b,
                path
            };
        }),
        tap(data => {
              this._items.next(data);
        })
    );
}
```

- `tap` is used to apply side effects and doesn't change the emitted value
- `map` is used to transform the emitted value

Answer (score 0):

use async/ await and promise on your API function

```
 async getDataFromAPI() 
  {
    return   { await  this._httpClient.get(URL).toPromise() }
  }
```